# Challenges with Production Build

Tags: extjs

Step 1
sencha -sdk C:/Users/lperepol/Downloads/SenchaEnterpriseExtJS/Unzip_7.xx/ext-7.3.1/ext-7.3.1 generate app -ext CDW ./CDW

Step 2
sencha app build
Then move the production folder to Web Server. App displays fine.

Step 3
Add a chart.
sencha app watch -- Chart displays fine.

Step 4
sencha app build
Then move the production folder to Web Server. App does not display web server error.

How do I get charts to display on a production web server? In development, everything works but not when moved to a Web Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure in your app.json you have:

Charts in the requires section.

```
"requires": [
        "exporter@7.3.1",
        "calendar@7.3.1",
        "charts@7.3.1",
        "font-awesome" 
    ],
```

a manifest defined in the bootstrap property.

The bootstrap section should be there but you may have to add the manifest property.

```
"bootstrap": {
        "base": "${app.dir}",
        "manifest": {
            "path": "bootstrap.json",
            "exclude": ""
        },
        "microloader": "bootstrap.js",
        "css": "bootstrap.css"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the response that led me in the right direction! Adding items to the requires array in the chart view solved the issue. The charts are displaying now on a remote web server -->  [CDW](https://cdw.cani.ca/)

```
requires: [
    'Ext.chart.CartesianChart',
    'Ext.chart.axis.Category3D',
    'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric3D',
    'Ext.chart.grid.HorizontalGrid3D',
    'Ext.chart.grid.VerticalGrid3D'
    'Ext.chart.interactions.ItemHighlight',
    'Ext.chart.interactions.PanZoom',
    'Ext.chart.series.Bar3D',
    'Ext.chart.series.Line',
    'Ext.chart.theme.*',
    'Ext.draw.modifier.Highlight',
],
```

Comment: Happy it helped!   There is another mode that I should have mentioned...  Testing mode is the same as development mode but the files are loaded un-compressed.  Makes it easier to figure out what is broken when something works in development mode but not in production.  so sencha app build testing